# How to get year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds of the current moment in Java?

Tags: java, date

How can I get the year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds of the current moment in Java? I would like to have them as `Strings`.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You can use the getters of [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) for that.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
int year = now.getYear();
int month = now.getMonthValue();
int day = now.getDayOfMonth();
int hour = now.getHour();
int minute = now.getMinute();
int second = now.getSecond();
int millis = now.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND); // Note: no direct getter available.

System.out.printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millis);
```

Or, when you're not on Java 8 yet, make use of [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Note: zero based!
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int millis = now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

System.out.printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millis);
```

Either way, this prints as of now:

```
2010-04-16 15:15:17.816
```

To convert an `int` to `String`, make use of [`String#valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-).

---

If your intent is *after all* to arrange and display them in a human friendly string format, then better use either Java8's [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) ([tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)),

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
String format1 = now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
String format2 = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT")).format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
String format3 = now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH));

System.out.println(format1);
System.out.println(format2);
System.out.println(format3);
```

or when you're not on Java 8 yet, use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Date now = new Date(); // java.util.Date, NOT java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp!
String format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH).format(now);
String format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).format(now);
String format3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(now);

System.out.println(format1);
System.out.println(format2);
System.out.println(format3);
```

Either way, this yields:

```
2010-04-16T15:15:17.816
Fri, 16 Apr 2010 15:15:17 GMT
20100416151517
```

#### See also:

- [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/)

Comment: If you are going to use printf then you might as well just use the formats for Date/Times instead of using the intermediary step i.e. "%1$tm %1$te,%1$tY", c (see java.util.Formatter for the full syntax)

Comment: @M. Jessup: That's indeed nicer. I've however never used it, so I couldn't enter it from top of head, the above is just for demo purposes. Regardless, I would rather grab `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` for that particular task :)

Comment: I would strongly suggest using joda-time, since its much nicer and understandable API compared to the badly designed Dates and Calendars that Java offers directly.

Comment: I prefer this one, especially in i18n work to get startTime or endTime : `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());`

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

Comment: As a detail, I recommend you pass a `ZoneId` to `LocalDateTime.now()`. This way you are making explicit that the operation is time zone dependent, and telling the reader you’ve made a conscious choice of time zone. For example `ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Salta")` or `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is not the appropriate class for this. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, it *cannot* be used to track a specific moment, it is *not* a point on the timeline. Use `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, or `OffsetDateTime` instead.

Comment: @BasilBourque The question did not mention "current time in a specific time zone". So the `LocalDateTime` is perfectly fine. Obviously, you need `ZonedDateTime` if you need "current time in a specific time zone", but this wasn't asked.

Comment: I searched for hours the milliseconds of a second getter, this answer made immediately clear that there is none.

Answer (score 31):

Switch to [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and you can do this in three lines

```
DateTime jodaTime = new DateTime();

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println("jodaTime = " + formatter.print(jodaTime));
```

You also have direct access to the individual fields of the date without using a Calendar.

```
System.out.println("year = " + jodaTime.getYear());
System.out.println("month = " + jodaTime.getMonthOfYear());
System.out.println("day = " + jodaTime.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println("hour = " + jodaTime.getHourOfDay());
System.out.println("minute = " + jodaTime.getMinuteOfHour());
System.out.println("second = " + jodaTime.getSecondOfMinute());
System.out.println("millis = " + jodaTime.getMillisOfSecond());
```

Output is as follows:

```
jodaTime = 2010-04-16 18:09:26.060

year = 2010
month = 4
day = 16
hour = 18
minute = 9
second = 26
millis = 60
```

According to http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java.
>   From Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time
>   (JSR-310).

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance, with its team advising migration to the java.time classes. Both Joda-Time and java.time are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

Answer (score 12):

```
    // Java 8
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getYear());       // 2015
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getMonth());      // SEPTEMBER
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth()); // 29
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getHour());       // 7
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getMinute());     // 36
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getSecond());     // 51
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND)); // 100

    // Calendar
    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));         // 2015
    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH ) + 1);   // 9
    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); // 29
    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));  // 7
    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));       // 35
    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));       // 32
    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));  // 481

    // Joda Time
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getYear());           // 2015
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getMonthOfYear());    // 9
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getDayOfMonth());     // 29
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getHourOfDay());      // 7
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getMinuteOfHour());   // 19
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getSecondOfMinute()); // 16
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getMillisOfSecond()); // 174

    // Formatted
    // 2015-09-28 17:50:25.756
    System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    // 2015-09-28T17:50:25.772
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date()));

    // Java 8
    // 2015-09-28T17:50:25.810
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());

    // joda time
    // 2015-09-28 17:50:25.839
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").print(new org.joda.time.DateTime()));
```

Answer (score 6):

With Java 8 and later, use the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

```
ZonedDateTime.now().getYear();
ZonedDateTime.now().getMonthValue();
ZonedDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth();
ZonedDateTime.now().getHour();
ZonedDateTime.now().getMinute();
ZonedDateTime.now().getSecond();
```

[`ZonedDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now--) is a static method returning the current date-time from the system clock in the default time-zone. All the get methods return an `int` value.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is precisely the wrong class for this. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, it *cannot* be used to track a specific moment, it is *not* a point on the timeline. Use `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, or `OffsetDateTime` instead.

Comment: You're right. I've modified my answer to use a `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now(                    // Capture current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )   // Specify desired/expected time zone. Or pass `ZoneId.systemDefault` for the JVM’s current default time zone.
)                                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.getMinute()                          // Extract the minute of the hour of the time-of-day from the `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

> 42

## `ZonedDateTime`

To capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Call any of the many getters to pull out pieces of the date-time.

```
int    year        = zdt.getYear() ;
int    monthNumber = zdt.getMonthValue() ;
String monthName   = zdt.getMonth().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.JAPAN ) ;  // Locale determines human language and cultural norms used in localizing. Note that `Locale` has *nothing* to do with time zone.
int    dayOfMonth  = zdt.getDayOfMonth() ;
String dayOfWeek   = zdt.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ; 
int    hour        = zdt.getHour() ;  // Extract the hour from the time-of-day.
int    minute      = zdt.getMinute() ;
int    second      = zdt.getSecond() ;
int    nano        = zdt.getNano() ;
```

The *java.time* classes resolve to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Your Question asked for the fraction of a second in [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). Obviously, you can divide by a million to truncate nanoseconds to milliseconds, at the cost of possible data loss. Or use the [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum for such conversion.

```
long millis = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis( zdt.getNano() ) ;
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

To produce a `String` to combine pieces of text, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Search Stack Overflow for more info on this.

## `Instant`

Usually best to track moments in UTC. To adjust from a zoned date-time to UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

And go back again.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

A couple of other Answers use the `LocalDateTime` class. That class in not appropriate to the purpose of tracking actual moments, specific moments on the timeline, as it intentionally lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

So what is `LocalDateTime` good for? Use `LocalDateTime` when you intend to apply a date & time to *any locality* or *all localities*, rather than one specific locality.

[image]

For example, Christmas this year starts at the `LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-12-25T00:00:00" )`. That value has no meaning until you apply a time zone (a `ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Christmas happens first in [Kiribati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiribati), then later in New Zealand and far east Asia. Hours later Christmas starts in India. More hour later in Africa & Europe. And still not Xmas in the Americas until several hours later. Christmas starting in any *one* place should be represented with `ZonedDateTime`. Christmas *everywhere* is represented with a `LocalDateTime`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

Or use java.sql.Timestamp.  Calendar is kinda heavy,I would recommend against using it 
in production code. Joda is better.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class DateTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood both the question and the use of the sql timestamp. You would normally use `new Date()` here. But how would you get the separate parts from it easily as requested?

Comment: FYI, `java.sql.Timestamp` was supplanted by the `java.time.Instant` with the arrival of JDBC 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

in java 7 Calendar one line

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

Comment: The troublesome Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes are now outdated, supplanted entirely by the java.time classes. See [the Answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654053/642706) for the modern approach. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formatting pattern 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss aa' to get date as **21-10-2020 20:53:42 pm**

Answer (score -2):

Look at the API documentation for the java.util.Calendar class and its derivatives (you may be specifically interested in the GregorianCalendar class).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score -2):

Calendar now = new Calendar() // or new GregorianCalendar(), or whatever flavor you need

now.MONTH
now.HOUR

etc.

Comment: Hi, I have a hard time in understanding why you are repeating an already given answer in a poor manner. Please elaborate :)

Comment: `MONTH` and `HOUR` are static constants of `Calendar`, not instance properties.