# Java string to date conversion

Tags: java, string, date, time, data-conversion

What is the best way to convert a `String` in the format 'January 2, 2010' to a `Date` in Java?

Ultimately, I want to break out the month, the day, and the year as integers so that I can use

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setMonth()..
date.setYear()..
date.setDay()..
date.setlong currentTime = date.getTime();
```

to convert the date into time.

Comment: Note that many of the answers ignore subtleties like locales and timezones. I'd recommend a close reading of the documentation for the Date, Calendar, TimeZone, Locale, and SimpleDateFormat classes before using any of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735023/convert-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: Java 8 provides a new Date/Time API. If you are using Java 8 (or newer) you should have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22180505/1115554

Comment: All the setters of `Date` are deprecated.

Comment: @micha’s point is a good one, the newer classes are so much nicer to work with, come with so much fewer negative surprises and model your date and time requirements so much more accurately. You may use them with Java 6 and 7 too if you can live with a dependency on [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: For an insight into the complexity of date/time parsing and how to do it with JDK 8's `java.time` API, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508200/145989

Answer (score 1844, accepted):

That's the hard way, and those `java.util.Date` setter methods have been deprecated since Java 1.1 (1997). Moreover, the whole `java.util.Date` class was de-facto deprecated (discommended) since introduction of `java.time` API in Java 8 (2014).

Simply format the date using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with a pattern matching the input string ([the tutorial is available here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)).

In your specific case of "January 2, 2010" as the input string:

1. "January" is the full text month, so use the `MMMM` pattern for it
2. "2" is the short day-of-month, so use the `d` pattern for it.
3. "2010" is the 4-digit year, so use the `yyyy` pattern for it.

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(string, formatter);
System.out.println(date); // 2010-01-02
```

Note: if your format pattern happens to contain the time part as well, then use [`LocalDateTime#parse(text, formatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) instead of [`LocalDate#parse(text, formatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)). And, if your format pattern happens to contain the time zone as well, then use [`ZonedDateTime#parse(text, formatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)) instead.

Here's an extract of relevance from [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), listing all available format patterns:

| Symbol | Meaning | Presentation | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `G` | era | text | AD; Anno Domini; A |
| `u` | year | year | 2004; 04 |
| `y` | year-of-era | year | 2004; 04 |
| `D` | day-of-year | number | 189 |
| `M`/`L` | month-of-year | number/text | 7; 07; Jul; July; J |
| `d` | day-of-month | number | 10 |
| `Q`/`q` | quarter-of-year | number/text | 3; 03; Q3; 3rd quarter |
| `Y` | week-based-year | year | 1996; 96 |
| `w` | week-of-week-based-year | number | 27 |
| `W` | week-of-month | number | 4 |
| `E` | day-of-week | text | Tue; Tuesday; T |
| `e`/`c` | localized day-of-week | number/text | 2; 02; Tue; Tuesday; T |
| `F` | week-of-month | number | 3 |
| `a` | am-pm-of-day | text | PM |
| `h` | clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12) | number | 12 |
| `K` | hour-of-am-pm (0-11) | number | 0 |
| `k` | clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-24) | number | 0 |
| `H` | hour-of-day (0-23) | number | 0 |
| `m` | minute-of-hour | number | 30 |
| `s` | second-of-minute | number | 55 |
| `S` | fraction-of-second | fraction | 978 |
| `A` | milli-of-day | number | 1234 |
| `n` | nano-of-second | number | 987654321 |
| `N` | nano-of-day | number | 1234000000 |
| `V` | time-zone ID | zone-id | America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30 |
| `z` | time-zone name | zone-name | Pacific Standard Time; PST |
| `O` | localized zone-offset | offset-O | GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00; |
| `X` | zone-offset 'Z' for zero | offset-X | Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15; |
| `x` | zone-offset | offset-x | +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15; |
| `Z` | zone-offset | offset-Z | +0000; -0800; -08:00; |

Do note that it has several [predefined formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined) for the more popular patterns. So instead of e.g. `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);`, you could use `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`. This is possible because they are, on the contrary to `SimpleDateFormat`, thread safe. You could thus also define your own, if necessary.

For a particular input string format, you don't need to use an explicit `DateTimeFormatter`: a standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date, like 2016-09-26T17:44:57Z, can be parsed directly with [`LocalDateTime#parse(text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) as it already uses the [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) formatter. Similarly, [`LocalDate#parse(text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) parses an ISO date without the time component (see [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE)), and [`ZonedDateTime#parse(text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) parses an ISO date with an offset and time zone added (see [`ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)).

---

### Pre-Java 8

In case you're not on Java 8 yet, or are forced to use `java.util.Date`, then format the date using [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) using a format pattern matching the input string.

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 2010
```

Note the importance of the explicit `Locale` argument. If you omit it, then it will use the [default locale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()) which is not necessarily English as used in the month name of the input string. If the locale doesn't match with the input string, then you would confusingly get a `java.text.ParseException` even though when the format pattern seems valid.

Here's an extract of relevance from [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), listing all available format patterns:

| Letter | Date or Time Component | Presentation | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `G` | Era designator | Text | AD |
| `y` | Year | Year | 1996; 96 |
| `Y` | Week year | Year | 2009; 09 |
| `M`/`L` | Month in year | Month | July; Jul; 07 |
| `w` | Week in year | Number | 27 |
| `W` | Week in month | Number | 2 |
| `D` | Day in year | Number | 189 |
| `d` | Day in month | Number | 10 |
| `F` | Day of week in month | Number | 2 |
| `E` | Day in week | Text | Tuesday; Tue |
| `u` | Day number of week | Number | 1 |
| `a` | Am/pm marker | Text | PM |
| `H` | Hour in day (0-23) | Number | 0 |
| `k` | Hour in day (1-24) | Number | 24 |
| `K` | Hour in am/pm (0-11) | Number | 0 |
| `h` | Hour in am/pm (1-12) | Number | 12 |
| `m` | Minute in hour | Number | 30 |
| `s` | Second in minute | Number | 55 |
| `S` | Millisecond | Number | 978 |
| `z` | Time zone | General time zone | Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00 |
| `Z` | Time zone | RFC 822 time zone | -0800 |
| `X` | Time zone | ISO 8601 time zone | -08; -0800; -08:00 |

Note that the patterns are case sensitive and that text based patterns of four characters or more represent the full form; otherwise a short or abbreviated form is used if available. So e.g. `MMMMM` or more is unnecessary.

Here are some examples of valid `SimpleDateFormat` patterns to parse a given string to date:

| Input string | Pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT | `yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z` |
| Wed, Jul 4, '01 | `EEE, MMM d, ''yy` |
| 12:08 PM | `h:mm a` |
| 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time | `hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz` |
| 0:08 PM, PDT | `K:mm a, z` |
| 02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM | `yyyyy.MMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa` |
| Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700 | `EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z` |
| 010704120856-0700 | `yyMMddHHmmssZ` |
| 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700 | `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` |
| 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00 | `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` |
| 2001-W27-3 | `YYYY-'W'ww-u` |

An important note is that `SimpleDateFormat` is **not** thread safe. In other words, you should never declare and assign it as a static or instance variable and then reuse it from different methods/threads. You should always create it brand new within the method local scope.

Comment: Hi, in option `O`, how to let it print `UTC+08:00` instead of `GMT+08:00`. I couldn't get any example.

Comment: There are many ways to parse dates, here are [various use cases of DateFormat.parse](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/java.text.DateFormat/parse)

Comment: Hi BalusC, I have a string `20-JUN-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM`, need help to convert this to Date. Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: @mannedear oh sorry.. that was my mistake. Anyway I got the answer you can see it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982310/convert-human-date-local-time-gmt-to-date#50991959

Comment: What if we need to use API 23< and below? All this "parse" methods are for Java8+

Comment: I am getting an unexpected date format for a given date and format. Like the date String is `2022-11-01 08:32:08` This date is saved with Carbon Laravel using the format `Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` and in Java parsing it using `(new SimpleDateFormat("y-m-d H:m:s")).parse(date)` and getting `Mon Jan 31 14:14:15 GMT+05:00 2022` I wanted it to be in the same format of the input. Checked it with `yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s` but not getting what I want. Sorry for a long comment.

Comment: Oh damn, an answer from 2010 telling me the stuff I was using in 2023 is outdated lol.

Answer (score 84):

Ah yes the Java Date discussion, again.  To deal with date manipulation we use [Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), [GregorianCalendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), and [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  For example using your January date as input:

```
Calendar mydate = new GregorianCalendar();
String mystring = "January 2, 2010";
Date thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(mystring);
mydate.setTime(thedate);
//breakdown
System.out.println("mydate -> "+mydate);
System.out.println("year   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println("month  -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("dom    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("dow    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
System.out.println("hour   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.HOUR));
System.out.println("minute -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println("second -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.SECOND));
System.out.println("milli  -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
System.out.println("ampm   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
System.out.println("hod    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Then you can manipulate that with something like:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
mydate.set(Calendar.YEAR,2009);
mydate.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.FEBRUARY);
mydate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,25);
mydate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
mydate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
mydate.set(Calendar.SECOND,now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
// or with one statement
//mydate.set(2009, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 25, now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
System.out.println("mydate -> "+mydate);
System.out.println("year   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println("month  -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("dom    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("dow    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
System.out.println("hour   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.HOUR));
System.out.println("minute -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println("second -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.SECOND));
System.out.println("milli  -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
System.out.println("ampm   -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
System.out.println("hod    -> "+mydate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Comment: Don't forget that January is month number... 0

Answer (score 68):

```
String str_date = "11-June-07";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date date = formatter.parse(str_date);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of separating declarations and definitions (though not done for the first variable)?

Answer (score 48):

With Java 8 we get a new Date / Time API ([JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).

The following way can be used to parse the date in Java 8 without relying on [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
 String str = "January 2nd, 2010";
```

---

```
// if we 2nd even we have changed in pattern also it is not working please workout with 2nd 
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM Q, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
```

---

```
// access date fields
int year = date.getYear(); // 2010
int day = date.getDayOfMonth(); // 2
Month month = date.getMonth(); // JANUARY
int monthAsInt = month.getValue(); // 1
```

---

[LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is the standard Java 8 class for representing a date (without time). If you want to parse values that contain date and time information you should use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). For values with timezones use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Both provide a `parse()` method similar to `LocalDate`:

```
LocalDateTime dateWithTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strWithDateAndTime, dateTimeFormatter);
ZonedDateTime zoned = ZonedDateTime.parse(strWithTimeZone, zoneFormatter);
```

The list formatting characters from [DateTimeFormatter Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
All letters 'A' to 'Z' and 'a' to 'z' are reserved as pattern letters. 
The following pattern letters are defined:

Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
 G       era                         text              AD; Anno Domini; A
 u       year                        year              2004; 04
 y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
 D       day-of-year                 number            189
 M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J
 d       day-of-month                number            10

 Q/q     quarter-of-year             number/text       3; 03; Q3; 3rd quarter
 Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
 w       week-of-week-based-year     number            27
 W       week-of-month               number            4
 E       day-of-week                 text              Tue; Tuesday; T
 e/c     localized day-of-week       number/text       2; 02; Tue; Tuesday; T
 F       week-of-month               number            3

 a       am-pm-of-day                text              PM
 h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)  number            12
 K       hour-of-am-pm (0-11)        number            0
 k       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-24)  number            0

 H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
 m       minute-of-hour              number            30
 s       second-of-minute            number            55
 S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
 A       milli-of-day                number            1234
 n       nano-of-second              number            987654321
 N       nano-of-day                 number            1234000000

 V       time-zone ID                zone-id           America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30
 z       time-zone name              zone-name         Pacific Standard Time; PST
 O       localized zone-offset       offset-O          GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00;
 X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
 x       zone-offset                 offset-x          +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
 Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;
```

Comment: How dows the fraction-of-second work ? If I use LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("20140920111713000",DateTimeFormatter.of‌​Pattern("yyyyMMddHHm‌​mssSSS")); it fail but if I use LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("20140920111713.000",DateTimeFormatter.o‌​fPattern("yyyyMMddHH‌​mmss.SSS")); it works

Answer (score 31):

While some of the answers are technically correct, they are not advisable.

- The java.util.Date & Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Because of flaws in design and implementation, avoid them. Fortunately we have our choice of two other excellent date-time libraries:

  - **[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)**
    This popular open-source free-of-cost library can be used across several versions of Java. Many examples of its usage may be found on StackOverflow. Reading some of these will help get you up to speed quickly.
  - **[java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)**
    This new set of classes are inspired by Joda-Time and defined by JSR 310. These classes are built into Java 8. A project is underway to backport these classes to Java 7, but that backporting is not backed by Oracle.
- As Kristopher Johnson correctly noted in his comment on the question, the other answers ignore vital issues of:

  - **Time of Day**
    Date has both a date portion and a time-of-day portion)
  - **Time Zone**
    The beginning of a day depends on the time zone. If you fail to specify a time zone, the JVM's default time zone is applied. That means the behavior of your code may change when run on other computers or with a modified time zone setting. Probably not what you want.
  - **Locale**
    The Locale's language specifies how to interpret the words (name of month and of day) encountered during parsing. (The [answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/642706) handles this properly.) Also, the Locale affects the output of some formatters when generating a string representation of your date-time.

## Joda-Time

A few notes about Joda-Time follow.

### Time Zone

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object truly knows its own assigned time zone. This contrasts the java.util.Date class which *seems* to have a time zone but does not.

Note in the example code below how we pass a time zone object to the formatter which parses the string. That time zone is used to interpret that date-time as having occurred in that time zone. So you need to think about and determine the time zone represented by that string input.

Since you have no time portion in your input string, Joda-Time assigns the first moment of the day of the specified time zone as the time-of-day. Usually this means `00:00:00` but not always, because of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or other anomalies. By the way, you can do the same to any DateTime instance by calling `withTimeAtStartOfDay`.

### Formatter Pattern

The characters used in a formatter's pattern are similar in Joda-Time to those in java.util.Date/Calendar but not exactly the same. Carefully read the doc.

### Immutability

We usually use the immutable classes in Joda-Time. Rather than modify an existing Date-Time object, we call methods that create a new fresh instance based on the other object with most aspects copied except where alterations were desired. An example is the call to `withZone` in last line below. [Immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) helps to make Joda-Time very thread-safe, and can also make some work more clear.

### Conversion

You will need java.util.Date objects for use with other classes/framework that do not know about Joda-Time objects. Fortunately, it is very easy to move back and forth.

Going from a java.util.Date object (here named `date`) to Joda-Time DateTime…

```
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, timeZone );
```

Going the other direction from Joda-Time to a java.util.Date object…

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

### Sample Code

```
String input = "January 2, 2010";

java.util.Locale locale = java.util.Locale.US;
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Pacific/Honolulu" ); // Arbitrarily chosen for example.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MMMM d, yyyy" ).withZone( timeZone ).withLocale( locale );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input );

System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTime in UTC/GMT: " + dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2010-01-02T00:00:00.000-10:00
dateTime in UTC/GMT: 2010-01-02T10:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 22):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date;
try {
    date = dateFormat.parse("2013-12-4");
    System.out.println(date.toString()); // Wed Dec 04 00:00:00 CST 2013

    String output = dateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println(output); // 2013-12-04
} 
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: This will return Wed Dec 04 00:00:00 GST 2013 as output not 2013-12-04

Comment: should be wrapped in a ParseException try/catch

Comment: This wont return values as expected. Please test before advising

Answer (score 20):

While on dealing with the SimpleDateFormat class, it's important to remember that Date is not thread-safe and you can not share a single Date object with multiple threads.

Also there is big difference between "m" and "M" where small case is used for minutes and capital case is used for month. The same with "d" and "D". This can cause subtle bugs which often get overlooked. See [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or *[Guide to Convert String to Date in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/step-by-step-guide-to-convert-string-to.html)* for more details.

Comment: This m/M difference cost me 5 minutes of frustration, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: I'm surprised nobody else mentioned this. Using SimpleDateFormat in Web applications (or any other multi-threaded app) is a big no-no. Up through Java 7, I've been using "FastDateFormat".

Answer (score 11):

You can use SimpleDateformat for  change string to date

```html
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strDate = "2000-01-01";
Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat parse method returns a date object. Then why use Date constructor?

Answer (score 7):

Simple two formatters we have used:

1. Which format date do we want?
2. Which format date is actually present?

We parse the full date to time format:

```
date="2016-05-06 16:40:32";

public static String setDateParsing(String date) throws ParseException {

    // This is the format date we want
    DateFormat mSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

    // This format date is actually present
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
    return mSDF.format(formatter.parse(date));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, SimpleDateFormat is not available with some of the client-side technologies, like [GWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit).

It's a good idea to go for Calendar.getInstance(), and your requirement is to compare two dates; go for long date.

Answer (score 5):

My humble test program. I use it to play around with the formatter and look-up long dates that I find in log-files (but who has put them there...).

**My test program:**

```
package be.test.package.time;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeWork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

        List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        //Formatting a date needs a timezone - otherwise the date get formatted to your system time zone.
        //Use 24h format HH. In 12h format hh can be in range 0-11, which makes 12 overflow to 0.
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        formatter.setTimeZone(timezone);

        Date now = new Date();

        //Test dates
        strings.add(formatter.format(now));
        strings.add("01-01-1970 00:00:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-1970 00:00:01.000");
        strings.add("01-01-1970 00:01:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-1970 01:00:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-1970 10:00:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-1970 12:00:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-1970 24:00:00.000");
        strings.add("02-01-1970 00:00:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-1971 00:00:00.000");
        strings.add("01-01-2014 00:00:00.000");
        strings.add("31-12-1969 23:59:59.000");
        strings.add("31-12-1969 23:59:00.000");
        strings.add("31-12-1969 23:00:00.000");

        //Test data
        longs.add(now.getTime());
        longs.add(-1L);
        longs.add(0L); //Long date presentation at - midnight 1/1/1970 UTC - The timezone is important!
        longs.add(1L);
        longs.add(1000L);
        longs.add(60000L);
        longs.add(3600000L);
        longs.add(36000000L);
        longs.add(43200000L);
        longs.add(86400000L);
        longs.add(31536000000L);
        longs.add(1388534400000L);
        longs.add(7260000L);
        longs.add(1417706084037L);
        longs.add(-7260000L);

        System.out.println("===== String to long =====");

        //Show the long value of the date
        for (String string: strings) {
            try {
                Date date = formatter.parse(string);
                System.out.println("Formated date : " + string + " = Long = " + date.getTime());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("===== Long to String =====");

        //Show the date behind the long
        for (Long lo : longs) {
            Date date = new Date(lo);
            String string = formatter.format(date);
            System.out.println("Formated date : " + string + " = Long = " + lo);        
        }
    }
}
```

**Test results:**

```
===== String to long =====
Formated date : 05-12-2014 10:17:34.873 = Long = 1417774654873
Formated date : 01-01-1970 00:00:00.000 = Long = 0
Formated date : 01-01-1970 00:00:01.000 = Long = 1000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 00:01:00.000 = Long = 60000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 01:00:00.000 = Long = 3600000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 10:00:00.000 = Long = 36000000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 12:00:00.000 = Long = 43200000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 24:00:00.000 = Long = 86400000
Formated date : 02-01-1970 00:00:00.000 = Long = 86400000
Formated date : 01-01-1971 00:00:00.000 = Long = 31536000000
Formated date : 01-01-2014 00:00:00.000 = Long = 1388534400000
Formated date : 31-12-1969 23:59:59.000 = Long = -1000
Formated date : 31-12-1969 23:59:00.000 = Long = -60000
Formated date : 31-12-1969 23:00:00.000 = Long = -3600000
===== Long to String =====
Formated date : 05-12-2014 10:17:34.873 = Long = 1417774654873
Formated date : 31-12-1969 23:59:59.999 = Long = -1
Formated date : 01-01-1970 00:00:00.000 = Long = 0
Formated date : 01-01-1970 00:00:00.001 = Long = 1
Formated date : 01-01-1970 00:00:01.000 = Long = 1000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 00:01:00.000 = Long = 60000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 01:00:00.000 = Long = 3600000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 10:00:00.000 = Long = 36000000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 12:00:00.000 = Long = 43200000
Formated date : 02-01-1970 00:00:00.000 = Long = 86400000
Formated date : 01-01-1971 00:00:00.000 = Long = 31536000000
Formated date : 01-01-2014 00:00:00.000 = Long = 1388534400000
Formated date : 01-01-1970 02:01:00.000 = Long = 7260000
Formated date : 04-12-2014 15:14:44.037 = Long = 1417706084037
Formated date : 31-12-1969 21:59:00.000 = Long = -7260000
```

Answer (score 2):

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/android-useful-methods-and-functions/)**

For **Android**

**Calendar.getInstance().getTime()** gives

```
Thu Jul 26 15:54:13 GMT+05:30 2018
```

**Use**

```
String oldDate = "Thu Jul 26 15:54:13 GMT+05:30 2018";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE LLL dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date updateLast = format.parse(oldDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

I worked on parsing String to LocalDateTime. I leave it here as example

```
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.parse("20180805 101010", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmss"));
```

And I got
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
  Date date1 = null;
  Date date2 = null;

  try {
    date1 = dateFormat.parse(t1);
    date2 = dateFormat.parse(t2);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
  String StDate = formatter.format(date1);
  String edDate = formatter.format(date2);

  System.out.println("ST  "+ StDate);
  System.out.println("ED "+ edDate);
```

Comment: Excuse me, aren’t you just repeating what is already in several obsolete and ill-advised answers using the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class and friends? I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat` and `Date`. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

From Date to String

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
return sdf.format(date);
```

From String to Date

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern); 
return sdf.parse(dateStr);
```

From date String to different format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat newSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date temp = sdf.parse(dateStr);
return newSdf.format(temp);
```

Source [link](https://www.polynique.com/programming-languages/convert-dates-and-strings-in-java-using-simpledateformat/).

Answer (score 0):

String to Date conversion:

```
private Date StringtoDate(String date) throws Exception {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
            if( !date.isEmpty()) {

                try {
                    java.util.Date normalDate = sdf1.parse(date);
                    sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(normalDate.getTime());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new Exception("Not able to Parse the date", e);
                }
            }
            return sqlDate;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String date = get_pump_data.getString("bond_end_date");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date datee = (Date)format.parse(date);
```