# Java get date using only the utility package

Tags: java

The following code gets the date:

```
private static String get_date() {
    return (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

using `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

How can I do the above only by using a `import java.util.*;`

Is it okay to do it like this? Why I get warnings?

```
Date date= new java.util.Date();
        String s = (date.getYear()+1900)+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getDay()+" "+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Copy the code of `SimpleDateFormat` into your code?

Comment: You can use Calendar and build the same String with "calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) etc.

Comment: ... what is the issue with the java.text package? It's a JRE package, after all..

Comment: It's for a univercity project and we must use only java.util.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654025/how-to-get-year-month-day-hours-minutes-seconds-and-milliseconds-of-the-cur

Comment: As to why you are getting warnings, those methods you are using are deprecated -- they have been marked for destruction and even though they might work, eventually they will not be supported.  I'm thinking your professor will not accept their use.  (Then again, your professor requiring you to not use anything outside of java.util is... funny.)

Answer (score 1):

String.format() is your friend.

```
public static String formatDate(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    String template = "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d";
    return String.format(template, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
        cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
        cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(formatDate(new Date()));
}
```